# Can we have event handling for jsp controls at server side in Spring MVC?

Tags: spring-mvc, model-view-controller, event-handling

In Swing we have action listeners for every control we add, and we handle all the events fired with those controls. Is there any similar method or way in Spring Model View Controller architecture to handle events of "Java Server Pages" controls like buttons, text boxes etc. in the controller at server side?

Comment: Can you expand your question to include specific details of what it is you wish to achieve, as currently your question is rather vague?

Comment: for example to handle button click we write function in Java script and call that function on a specific event(onclick), so can we do this at server side :

Answer (score 0):

In Spring MVC you can handle and verify those controls in JavaScript or at server side in controller. When any method(e.g. GET, POST etc.) calls the controller then your data goes to controller and you can handle those data.

Comment: Yes i know that we can handle all data at server side but my question is about access to controls event handling means i want to know that can we do event handling of control at server side.